# Creating a post image to show in a gallery

Tags: images, gallery

Sorry if this title of question is not clear. I have create a custom post template with the help of this plugin [Custom Content Type Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/)

With this plugin i create this [image], and i am at the **Second Level**. Particular, i want for each attachment post to be represented with the gallery. How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For me, nothing is clear... What is an "attachment post"? And a "gallery"? Can you translate this image into PHP? :::: *Side-note: Thubs or Thumbs, Madrit or Madrid?*

Comment: @braofilo, Sorry but hurry enough and the wireframe is very poor. Why is anything for you clear? At what point do you want clarification?

Comment: The wireframe is not the problem, and I only was pesky because this is the second time you write *Madrit* in a wireframe ;) :::: I need clarification for the 3 first questions on my previous comment.

Comment: @brasofilo for first I did edit the original image. I hope to help you more than before. 1) I upload the Custom Post Type with "attachment post" attributes. 2)When i press into the "attachment post" i want to be represented with the gallery. 3) In the third part of question, i can't translate this image into PHP.

Comment: @brasofilo any solution?

Comment: for more explanation, i want to create a gallery like this : http://demo.icprojects.net/photolencha/galleries/countries

Comment: Sorry, but am voting to close, note that other members have to agree with it and that this is just my opinion, but it seems either [*not a real question*](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#close) or a *work for me for free* type of Q (see related links in [this page](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)). ::: Suggestions: look for a gallery/slider plugin (Jetpack) that does it out of the box - try to find similar examples in form of `code` and add it to the Q. Regards,